# Angularjs : using html elements within ternary operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am totally new to Angular 1, I want to create a table where I am fetching data from an API and displaying it in rows. I don't want to display multiple rows with the same resourceId instead I have thought about creating a drop-down where I'll click and all the rows with similar resourceId will appear.

I have written this code inorder to hide the rows with the same resourceId, but this isn't working because Angular doesn't seem to
support embedding html elements in ternary operators. How can I achieve it?

```
<tr ng-repeat="report in data">
 {{report.resourceId === data[$index-1].resourceId ? 
 //Empty row
 :
 <td>{{report.reportId}}</td>
 <td>{{report.resourceId}}</td>
 <td>{{report.reason}}</td>
 }}
</tr>
```

The data array is like this:

```
data: [
  {
   reportId: "12",
   resourceId: "16241",
   reason: null
  },
  {
   reportId: "18",
   resourceId: "26387",
   reason: "It is biased or written by someone in the company"
  },
  {
   reportId: "19",
   resourceId: "26387",
   reason: "It is irrelevant"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of using ternary operation you can use `ng-if`

```
<tbody ng-repeat="report in data">
<tr ng-if="report.resourceId !== data[$index-1].resourceId">

 <td>{{report.reportId}}</td>
 <td>{{report.resourceId}}</td>
 <td>{{report.reason}}</td> 
</tr>
<tr ng-if="report.resourceId === data[$index-1].resourceId">
   <td></td>
<tr>
</tbody>
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.arr = {data: [
  {
   reportId: "12",
   resourceId: "16241",
   reason: null
  },
  {
   reportId: "18",
   resourceId: "26387",
   reason: "It is biased or written by someone in the company"
  },
  {
   reportId: "19",
   resourceId: "26387",
   reason: "It is irrelevant"
  }
]}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
 <tbody ng-repeat="report in arr.data">
<tr ng-if="report.resourceId !== arr.data[$index-1].resourceId">

 
 <td>{{report.reportId}}</td>
 <td>{{report.resourceId}}</td>
 <td>{{report.reason}}</td> 
</tr>
<tr ng-if="report.resourceId === arr.data[$index-1].resourceId">
   <td></td>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to be working for me. Will the <td>s still contain {{report.___}} or do I need to use something like 'this'. Sorry if this sounds dump, I am a noob when it comes to angular

Comment: you do not need to use the `this`. can you post the `data` array so i can create a demo

Comment: Added the data array

Comment: use `tbody` instead of `div`. check the demo